# code does not work on iphone

Tags: iphone, popen

The following  code doesn't work for device *Its not going into the while loop on device* but it runs on the simulator.

```
int status;
char value[1024] = "abcd";
FILE *fp = popen("openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1 2>&1", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    exit(1); // handle error
int i=0;
NSString *strAESKey;
while (fgets(value, 1024, fp) != NULL)
{
    i++;
    if(i==2)
    {
        strAESKey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",value];
        break;
    }
}

status = pclose(fp);
if (status == -1)
{
    /* Error reported by pclose() */
}
else
{
    /* Use macros described under wait() to inspect `status' in order
                         to determine success/failure of command executed by popen() */
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iOS application sandbox forbids use of the `fork` function, which `popen` uses.  The simulator doesn't use the sandbox, but devices do.

You will need to use the openssl library directly instead of using the command-line program.  The iOS public API doesn't include the openssl library, so you'll need to build a static library yourself.  You can find some help doing this by searching.  I'd start with [this blog post](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/).

Comment: We built the openssl library in our project and we could not generate the AES Key? can u please provide us some reference to generate the AES Key.

Comment: [Here is the source code of `openssl enc`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/enc.c), the command you were trying to run.